# WordPress: Divi Accordion Trigger - What is the best way to Trigger an Image Change as the user selects different sections of an accordion?

Tags: javascript, html, css, accordion, divi

WordPress site - Divi Theme/Framework. I'm trying to figure out what is the best way to trigger an image change (6 images total, one per tab) as the user selects different parts of the accordion. But the catch is the images are not inside the accordion, they are in the next column. At first, I thought I could do this with just CSS and the ID's but I was running into issues. *I know this can also be solved with JS but I am not as strong in JS as HTML/CSS these days.*

**Please let me know what you think is the best method to achieve something like this.**
**Cheers!**

**Each Section of the Accordion has its own class:**

```
 et_pb_accordion_0  
 et_pb_accordion_item_0   
 et_pb_accordion_item_1   
 et_pb_accordion_item_2     
 et_pb_accordion_item_3   
 et_pb_accordion_item_4  
 et_pb_accordion_item_5
```

**Open and Closed Class:**
**Open:**   et_pb_toggle_open
**Close:**  et_pb_toggle_close

I have added an ID to the Accordion of '#slidepick'

Here is the Output HTML from Divi for the first two sections of the Accordion:

```
<div id="slidepick" class="et_pb_module et_pb_accordion et_pb_accordion_0">
                
                
<div class="et_pb_toggle et_pb_module et_pb_accordion_item et_pb_accordion_item_0 et_pb_toggle_close">
                
                
    <h5 class="et_pb_toggle_title">Sample Content 1</h5>
    <div class="et_pb_toggle_content clearfix" style="display: none;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </div>
    </div><div class="et_pb_toggle et_pb_module et_pb_accordion_item et_pb_accordion_item_1 et_pb_toggle_open">
                
                
    <h5 class="et_pb_toggle_title">Sample Content 2</h5>
    <div class="et_pb_toggle_content clearfix" style="display: block;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
            </div>
```

[Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ul6zj.jpg)

Comment: Yes, you can achieve this with just HTML and CSS using the CSS `~` _subsequent sibling_ selector - but all 6 images will need to be siblings to the accordion items so that when you `:focus` on each you can select an image to display.

Comment: Can you give me an example? I figured it would be easier by ID.

Comment: Example: `.et_pb_accordion_item_1.et_pb_toggle_open ~ .image-1 {display: block;}` - but for this to work you will need to rearrange your markup, so the images are siblings to the accordion items. If the accordion items are marked up within a parent container, the `~` _subsequent sibling_ selector will not work.

Comment: I initially thought you'd need to use `tabindex="0"` and `:focus`, but now that I see you have the `.et_pb_toggle_open` class, then you should probably dare to dip your toe in the water of javascript - it will be a much more straightforward solution to use `if (myElement.classList.contains('myClass')) {myImageBlock.style.setProperty('display', 'block');` than to try to build a CSS-only solution using `~` in this case.

Comment: Ok @Rounin I think I understand what you mean, the issue is the image is in another column right now. Now I could probably mimic that... :thinking: To be clear your not saying it needs to be inside the Accordion correct but that it just needs to be a sibling, so that could be a Div right? Could I do this with a complicated set of divs? Now I am not afraid to use JS I am just not very good at it these days compared to my HTML and CSS so I may need a little more guidance with JS.

Comment: As far as I can tell (without seeing more of your markup), if you re-arrange the structure of your accordion to use the `~` selector, it looks like you'll then need to rewrite the accordion javascript. If so, I'm going to guess this will be more complex than writing a short JS to hide/show images based on whether an individual accordion section contains the class `.et_pb_toggle_open` or not. Regard this as a perfect opportunity to get your head around some JS basics. You will need the `classList` API (specifically `classList.contains()` and you will need `style.setProperty()`.

Comment: Hint: your best approach each time the user selects a new accordion section will be to switch off _all_ images and then identify which _one_ needs to be turned back on. Have a go at putting this together in your question above and ask if you have any further questions as you progress. I recognise this will seem daunting, but I promise you your perseverance will be rewarded.